# UIPopoverController iOS 8.3 - UIBarButtons and UISegmentedControl not shown after dismiss

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uipopovercontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

In our app when we present a `UIPopoverController`, after we dismiss it, if we navigate to any other screens that have `barButtonItems` or `segmentedControls`, these are not showing but they are intercepting the touch, so tapping on them works.

Even when we navigate to a new `UINavigationController`, it still doesn't work.
The `navigationBar` is visible, but the buttons or the `segmentedControls` on the view controller's view are not.
The weird thing is that if I enable `Color Blended Layers` I can see the buttons / `segmentedControl`.
It happens on multiple screen in our app where we have bar buttons or `segmentedControls`.

It happens only on iOS 8.3 (we build the app with iOS 8.3 SDK). We tried both presenting the pop over programatically and using the Present as Popover Segue.

The same code works on  iOS  < 8.3.

Has anyone encountered this issue?
I have attached some screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.
It seems that the tint color of the `UIWindow`(blue) was overriding the tint color of the `UINavigationBar` (white) so the `UIBarButtonItems` were actually blue.

I was setting them both in `AppDelegate` using `UIAppeareance`.

The solution was to avoid setting the tint color to the UIWindow and set it directly to the `UIView` subclasses that I was interested in (`UITableView` and `UIButton`)

I have no idea why this happened only after I dismissed the popover and only in iOS 8.3